# Deploy SharePoint 2010 Project to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2012, deploy

How to deploy a SharePoint 2010 wsp to a SharePoint 2013 site?

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but there are a lot of tutorials on the internet. Don't tell me that you did not find anything? Did you even do some research?

Comment: See here http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/03/24/deploy-sharepoint-2010-solutions-in-sharepoint-2013/ or here https://wmostafaw.wordpress.com/2013/04/18/deploying-sharepoint-2010-solution-on-sharepoint-2013/ or here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a0d84c35-0677-46ca-a60f-f8a05987f59b/how-can-i-deploy-sharepoint-2010-solution-to-2013 or....